# I'm using Stripe API in my code and I have an error : You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1EIw1gKIAV9zC39qQnFXKzi6

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I got an error saying :

> Customer cus_EmVoBWWrqnWw4W does not have a linked source with ID tok_1EIw1gKIAV9zC39qQnFXKzi6.

here is my code :

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_rUFQ9fpJoK9TlRVJs1nSYd6C");

$user = new User();

$email = $user->getEmail();
//creation du client
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $email,
));
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 2000,
    "currency" => "eur",
    "source" => $request ->request->get('stripeToken'),

    "description" => "Stripe connect - Order 36",
    "customer" => $customer->id

));
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_rUFQ9fpJoK9TlRVJs1nSYd6C");

$refund = \Stripe\Refund::create([
    'charge' => $charge,
    'amount' => 1000,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [save the card to the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) and then charge the customer. After that, unless the customer has multiple sources and you want to use a specific one, you won't need to pass `source` to `Charge::create`.